# 3 months rolling average on a table

Tags: sql-server

Query Thus far:

```
    SELECT Month
      ,Year
      ,vol
      --sum(vol) over (order by month,year  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND current row) sumnetvol,
      ,AVG(vol) OVER (ORDER BY Month, Year ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) '3monthra'
      ,name
      ,cnt
      ,costx
FROM(SELECT MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(monthnumber AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '01')) AS [Month]
           ,YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(monthnumber AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '01')) AS [Year]
           ,SUM(SumOfNetAmount) AS vol
           ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
           ,costx
           ,name
     FROM [ngl_OTB]
     GROUP BY costx
             ,MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(monthnumber AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '01'))
             ,YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(monthnumber AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '01'))
             ,name
             ,SumOfNetAmount) s
WHERE costx = '1000.002'
    AND name = 'ngl-raw'
ORDER BY Month
        ,Year
```

I need help on how to recursively set the [costx] and [name] columns to allow 3 months rolling avg of each [costx] and [name] correctly. All attempts provided wrong calculations like 3 months rolling avg was bleeding into other costx and name. My goal is to group all the data by costx and name and order by year and month, then performing a rolling 3 months avg on each costx using the value of [vol] for that [costx].

Comment: You might try something along the lines of doing your select statement for the `AVG` value you want for a given period, then use a `UNION` to get your previous 2 period's `AVG` values.

Comment: I found the solution using a partition by and cte